# Generate list of of files (with revision) which belongs to a specific cvs-tag

Tags: cvs

is there a way to generate a list of of files which belongs to a specific cvs-tag with revision.

e.g projectname_a includes following files
    - file_1 rev 1.1
    - file 2 rev 1.40
    ...

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution is to do a checkout with this tag somewhere. Takes a bit of disk space, though. If that bothers you, try what you get with the `-p` option. If this output contains file names, then you just need to filter them out.

Answer (score 0):

The list will be a little more verbose than what you want but you could simply do:

```
cvs log -S -N -r projectname_a
```

or possibly (if you don't have the project checked out):

```
cvs rlog -S -N -r projectname_a ModuleName
```

(you can use "." (w/o quotes) as the module name if you want to scan the entire repository)

If you only want the file names without the revision information, add `-R`.

Answer (score 0):

No need to check anything out - you can use the rls command (remote list). It will give you information in a slightly funny way but it is straightforward to process.

`cvs rls <MODULE> -r <TAG> -eR`

Here's my script snippet:

```
for NAME in `cvs rls ${MODULE} -r ${TAG} -eR  | grep -v ^$  | grep -v ^D | sed 's/ /~~/g'`
do

    FIRST_CHARACTER=`echo $NAME | cut -c1,1`
    if [ ${FIRST_CHARACTER} = "/" ] 
    then
        # This is a file
        FILE_NAME=`echo $NAME | awk -F/ '{print $2}'`
        VERSION=`echo $NAME | awk -F/ '{print $3}'`

        echo "${DIR_NAME}/${FILE_NAME},*${VERSION}*"

    else
        # This is a dir
        DIR_NAME=`echo $NAME | awk -F: '{print $1}'`
    fi
done
```